# What does disappointingly or frustratingly mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

> She disappointingly/frustratingly shook her head.

What does that sentence mean?

Did she express her disappointment/frustration or did her shaking head arouse disappointment/frustration?

Comment: She shook her head in a disappointing/frustrating manner. Meaning that, by seeing her shake her head, you could tell she was disappointed/frustrated.

Comment: I would say that the *-ing* suffix means that seeing her shake her head caused disappointment or frustration, actually.  Which is unusual and possibly not intended, so it might be in error.

Comment: Very simple: it means she shook her head in frustation or in disappointment. Same thing.

Comment: I actually think @Hellion may be right. As I look into it more, I'm leaning more towards a typo, also. I think it should either be -edly, or restructured using -ingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My inclination is to say that when "disappointingly" is used to modify the nature of a person's reported speech, it's likely that it is a typo, mis-hearing, or plain speaking error.  But, there is a certainly a clear difference in meaning between "frustratingly" and "frustratedly", and a similar distinction is available for "disappointingly" and "disappointedly".

*Disappointedly* clearly means "in a disappointed manner": that is, a manner that **expresses** disappointment.

*Disappointingly* would then mean "in a disappointing manner": that is, a manner that **causes** disappointment.

A possible sentence where both could do:

> "Can we go to the store?" Fred asked, excitedly.
>
> a: His mother shook her head disappointingly.
> *—her answer causes him disappointment.*
>
> b: His mother shook her head disappointedly.
> *—her head-shake expresses her own disappointment.*

I would expect to see *disappointingly* used in a situation where results came back worse than expected:

> We had hoped to see 20% annual growth.  Disappointingly, 2% was all they could manage.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of -ly at the end of a word normally makes it an adverb which modifies the verb, just the same as an adjective. To think of how a person might shake their head disappointingly, I visualize a situation where a person might do it. For example: A son/daughter getting bad grades then telling their parents. They might shake their heads disappointingly.